# Java API for fetching Twitter, Facebook & LInkedIn Analytics Data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter4j, linkedin-api, restfb, gnip

I just want to know whether it is possible to fetch analytics data of Social sites (Facebook, Twitter & LinkedIn) or not. 
I have made extensive research on this and found that :
LinkedIn : LinkedIn API doesn't have much for programmers. You can fetch your own profile details only and that too at a very basic level.
Twitter : WE can fetch real-time data using Twitter API but it can't provide you the access to analytics data.
Facebook : Graph API may serve but I 'm not sure whether I can fetch the aggregated data within a specified date-range or not.
Does anybody have any idea that how to fetch Analytics data of Social sites. I have to achieve this using Java library?

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook and LinkedIn Analytics data I have found the corresponding Java solutions :
Facebook : RestFb API - It is a third party API which can get you all the insights for your Facebook page like impressions, engagements etc.

LinkedIn : 'LinkedIn Company page API' - The required analytics data can be pulled by making the appropriate 'REST' requests.

I couldn't found any Java solution for pulling Twitter Analytics data. 'Gnip' provides an 'Engagement API' which can bring Twitter Analytics data but this API is written in 'Ruby' only. Does anybody know whether there is any Java alternative for this Engagement API is available or not?